# Xalan 2.7.1 and IIS 7 Cause HTML Truncation

Tags: xml, tomcat, iis-7, xalan, ajp

I have a rather sticky problem for which I've done a lot of research but have had no luck in finding a solution.

I have a web application comprised of Tomcat servlets. Tomcat is running on a Windows 2008 R2 server and uses the Apache ISAPI Redirector 1.2.37 in IIS for redirection to/from Tomcat (uses ajp13).

My application manages a library of XML files. When requested by a client (browser), a servlet uses XSL to transform the XML file to HTML.  The HTML is passed back to IIS thence back to the browser for display. Xalan is the implementation used for JAXP javax.xml.transform.  This architecture has worked well for several years.

Recently, we upgraded from Xalan 2.7.0 to 2.7.1 and discovered the HTML for some XML files is being truncated when viewed in the browser.

After some trial-and-error investigation, here is what we know:

1. Truncation only occurs when the source XML file is > ~1.7 MB.
2. The HTML is truncated at the same location every time. (buffer size issue??)
3. I tried redirecting the output from Xalan directly to a file ... no truncation.
4. Truncation only occurs when Xalan 2.7.1 is used with IIS 7

   Xalan 2.7.1 + IIS 7 = truncation

   Xalan 2.7.1 + IIS 6 = no truncation

   Xalan 2.7.0 + IIS 7 = no truncation
5. The ISAPI redirector log contains the following messages:

   ```
   [error] isapi_write_client::jk_isapi_plugin.c (1250): WriteClient failed with 534 (0x00000216)      

   [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1945): Writing to client aborted or client network problems

   [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2607): (ajp13w) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)

   [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1400): service failed, worker ajp13w is in local error state

   [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1419): unrecoverable error 200, request failed. Client failed in the middle of request, we can't recover to another instance.

   [info] HttpExtensionProc::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2257): service() failed because client aborted connection
   ```

Given items 4 and 5 above, it is not clear who is the culprit (IIS, the redirector, Xalan, or Tomcat ... or all of them).

Any suggestions will be wonderfully appreciated.

Comment: From the errors alone looks like an IIS or JK issue.  Can you confirm the timings of your tests and also that in the cases that work if you double the file size they continue to work.  It is possible your XML processing takes 3 minutes and IIS kills the connection.  So the implication is that upgrading Xalan slowed down processing ?  Do you have chunking enabled in JK ?  The file that you do receive each time is exactly identical, byte-for-byte upto the length received ?  This maybe more a Server Overflow question ?

Comment: @DarrylMiles - Thanks for reply. I agree it seems to be IIS or JK. I haven't timed the processing, but there is no perceptible difference between old Xalan and new. Processing is 4 - 6 seconds at most. The HTML is byte-for-byte repeatable (even on different servers), which leads me to believe it is not timing related.

Comment: Are you able to use FireBug on FireFox or 'wget -d -v' on Linux as a tool to pretend to be a different client implementation and confirm exactly what the view is from that side.  Also confirm if HTTP chunking is being used or not.  In the JK DLL there is an option to enabled/disable chunking (this should be thought of as a different chunking to that the client sees between IIS and JK) does not make any difference ?

Comment: @DarrylMiles - FireBug and IE Dev Tool both show the HTML is truncated.  FWIW, the Tomcat localhost_access log shows a 200 status and 3189404 bytes when no truncation occurs, and a 200 status and 2555272 bytes when truncation occurs.  I tried enabling chunked encoding (added "enable_chunked_encoding=1" to isapi_redirector.properties), but it slows the transformation considerably ... after several minutes the page times out. I also tried setting the redirector log_level to "debug", but the page timed out after the redirector log reached 31 MB.  I appreciate your help.